# Custom tab bar with shade background in android

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, custom-controls

I have created a custom tab layout which look like this,I want to make the background of top bar same as bottom bar that mean shaded in two part how could i do this,please suggest:

this is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/bac_tab"
android:id="@+id/mymain_layout" android:weightSum="1">

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/bac_tab">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.5dip"
            android:background="#000" />
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:layout_marginBottom ="5dip"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dip" android:layout_marginRight="30dip" android:background="@null"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />

        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/main">
                <ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#ffffff" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                <TextView android:id="@+id/empty" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="" android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/mainlayout" android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/empty" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="" android:textColor="#000000" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
<RelativeLayout android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:background="@drawable/bac_tab">

</RelativeLayout>
```

and bac_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<item>        
    <shape>
        <gradient
             android:endColor="#000000"
             android:startColor="#696969"
             android:centerColor="#696969"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke

            android:color="#696969" />
       <padding
            android:left="2dp"
            android:top="3dp"
            android:right="2dp"
            android:bottom="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the desirable result by using the transparent background for TabHost and use the shaded background as first layer:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/bac_tab"
android:id="@+id/mymain_layout" android:weightSum="1">

*<!---by adding this in the background----->

    <RelativeLayout android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="51dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/newbac"></RelativeLayout>

    <!---------------------------------------------------------->*

    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" ***android:background="@drawable/@android:color/transparent">***
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.5dip"
                android:background="#000" />
            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:layout_marginBottom ="5dip"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip" android:layout_marginRight="30dip" android:background="@null"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <LinearLayout android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/main">
                    <ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:background="#ffffff" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/empty" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="" android:textColor="#000000" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/mainlayout" android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/empty" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="" android:textColor="#000000" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
    <RelativeLayout android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:background="@drawable/bac_tab">

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using layer-list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item>
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle"
            >

            <gradient
                android:endColor="#000000"
             android:startColor="#696969"
             android:angle="270"
             android:centerColor="#696969"


                android:type="linear"
                />    
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```